# How to bypass WSGI error in django filter

Tags: django, filter

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Transfer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) 

name=models.CharField(max_length=55)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Is it possible to make a request like this without WSGI error?

```
result = Transfer.objects.filter(name=request.name)
```

Comment: it would be good i you showed your trace

Comment: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 0):

filter()
filter(**kwargs)
Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.

The lookup parameters (**kwargs) should be in the format described in Field lookups below.

Where charfield == String object, so try to str(request.name)

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show it with an example????

Comment: result = Transfer.objects.filter(name=str(request.name))

Comment: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: What kind of name are you trying to retrieve from request.name ?

Comment: the one in the model

Comment: If WSGIRequest does not have attribute 'name' , request.name is not valid. Do you want to retieve a name when someone post something or get ? Could you share more details about this request ?